# JAVA: What are the advantages of an InvocationHandler over an implementation of an Interface?

Tags: java, interface, mocking, implementation, invocationhandler

In class today, we were talking about reflection in Java programming. A part of the lesson today was about using **InvocationHandler**s in Java, rather than just implementing an interface.
When I asked the teacher what the advantages were of using an invocation handler, there wasn't a clear answer.
So let's say we have an interface **Plugin**

```
public interface Plugin {
    void calculate(double a, double b);
    String getCommand();
}
```

you can easily implement this interface in a class **Multiply**

```
public class Multiply implements Plugin {
    @Override
    public void calculate(double a, double b){
         return a * b;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCommand(){
         return "*";
    }
}
```

Then why would I prefer another implementation using an **InvocationHandler**?

```
 public class MyMock {
     public static Object createMock(Class myClass) {
         InvocationHandler handler = new MyInvocationHandler();
         Object result = Proxy.newProxyInstance(myClass.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{myClass}, handler);
         return result;
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) is a *dynamic* [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), allowing you to alter the behaviour of objects at **runtime** instead of having to decide it at **compile-time**.

For example, let's say we want to return only nulls during the night. If you were to implement it statically, you would need to write the logic into all the classes with something like

```
if(isNight())
    return null;
return normalValue;
```

This requires that you can actually change the class, and you would need to change **all** the classes.

However with a `Proxy`, you can write the above logic into the `InvocationHandler` and the normal classes won't even know that their values aren't used during the night. Instead of the original class, your code is now using the dynamic proxy, but it won't know the difference.

This also allows you to have multiple `InvocationHandlers`, so you could run your code with parameters to decide if you want to log calls, prevent calls for security reasons, or any other such thing, which would be quite impossible to do with static implementations.

---

You're unlikely to use those classes directly though, as they're quite low level. However [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) uses either dynamic proxies or bytecode manipulation to achieve its task. If you've ever used Spring, you've most likely used an `InvocationHandler` without knowing it. When you put `@Transactional` on a method, an `InvocationHandler` is what will intercept the method call and start (and end) the transaction for you.

Comment: How does it alter the behavior at runtime, given the proxy code must be compiled? Do you mean the main webserver, for example, can be running, meanwhile a client can create the proxy and alter the behavior without recompiling the main webserver code?

Answer (score 6):

`InvocationHandler` together with `Proxy` allow implementation of an interface at runtime, without the faff of compiling interface-specfic code. It is often used to mediate access to an object of a class that implements the same interface. `Proxy` **does not** allow changing the behaviour of existing objects or classes.

For instance, it can be used in remote method calling on the client side, forwarding method call across a network to a server.

My first use of `Proxy` was for logging method calls to a wide interface that represented command received over a wire format. This easily produced *very consistent* debug output, but required little maintenance when the interface changed.

Java annotation interfaces may be represented by a `Proxy` proxy object at runtime, to prevent an explosion of classes.

`java.beans.EventHandler` was useful before lambdas and method references came along, to implement event listeners without bloating jars.

Answer (score 5):

As per a more specific or real-world example, you may run into these kind of reflection usages more using a third-party or open-source API. A very popular example of this would be minecraft, specifically Bukkit/Spigot.

This api is used to write plugins, which the main server then loads and runs. This means you're not 100% in control of some of the code that exists in that codebase, inviting solutions using reflection. Specifically, when you want to *intercept* calls being made in the API (or even another plugin's API, e.g. Vault for those familiar), you may look to use a `Proxy`.

We'll stick with the minecraft example, but we're parting from bukkit's api here (and pretending it's not accepting PRs). Say there's a part of the API that just doesn't *quite* work the way you need.

```
public interface Player {
    //This method handles all damage! Hooray!
    public void damagePlayer(Player source, double damage);
}
```

This is great, but if we want to code something where we could find out if a player was damaged (maybe to make cool effects?), we'd need to modify the source (not possible for distributed plugins), or we'd need to find a way to figure out when `#damagePlayer` has been called and with what values. So in comes a `Proxy`:

```
public class PlayerProxy implements IvocationHandler {

    private final Player src;

    public PlayerProxy(Player src) {
        this.src = src;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        //Proceed to call the original Player object to adhere to the API
        Object back = m.invoke(this.src, args);
        if (m.getName().equals("damagePlayer") && args.length == 2) {
            //Add our own effects!
            //Alternatively, add a hook so you can register multiple things here, and avoid coding directly inside a Proxy
            if (/* 50% random chance */) {
                //double damage!
                args[1] = (double) args[1] * 2;
                //or perhaps use `source`/args[0] to add to a damage count?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With our Proxy, we've effectively created a *fake* Player class, one which will simply call the methods in place for `Player`. If our `PlayerProxy` is invoked with `myPlayerProxy.someOtherMethod(...)`, then it will happily pass along a call to `myPlayerProxy.src.someOtherMethod(...)` via reflection (the `m#invoke` in the method above).

Simply put, you hot-potato the objects in the library to suit your needs:

```
//we'll use this to demonstrate "replacing" the player variables inside of the server
Map<String, Player> players = /* a reflected instance of the server's Player objects, mapped by name. Convenient! */;
players.replaceAll((name, player) -> 
    (PlayerProxy) Proxy.newProxyInstance(/* class loader */, new Class<?>[]{Player.class}, new PlayerProxy(player)));
```

InvocationHandler can handle multiple interfaces too. By using a generic `Object` to pass along the invocations, you can then listen to a variety of different methods in the API all within the same `Proxy` instance.

Comment: So does it need the "damagePlayer" function to receive itself as the "Player source" parameter for the proxy to work?

Comment: So is this why Spring uses annotations, so it can easily wrap stuff with proxies by detecting the annotations?

Comment: Basically in the example above, you have a "real" object, and then a copy "proxy" object which wraps it. You then swap the "real" object out with the "proxy" object, so all calls to the original are now routed through the proxy. The `invoke` method is what is called for _any_ method call, we're just cherry picking which ones we care about. Annotation processing is a little different, they're more akin to markers for members of interest.